# Please critique my pending website's home page with these two questions:

Tags: website-design, critique, visualization, usability

I have the following questions regarding my design:

- Does my website have a professional, high-end feel? Why are why not?
- Does my current "Call To Action" button stand out or can you find it easily without much thought?

I'm marketing to potential clients who offer high-end products and/or services.

[image]

**//////////// Updated: January 27, 2015 ////////////**

Based on your feedback, I have modified my home page and wanted to show you what your efforts have helped me to produce. The footer area is empty now because I'm reworking it.

[image]

Comment: I can't read whatever cursive font that is, image caption is… awkward, you design designs, why is your logo logo?, white background and dark purple background contrast a lot – why are you contrasting it so much?, you don't need the >> character on the button, it doesn't look full width

Comment: I applaud you having a market to focus on. I think you need to work on the description of it, though. Is it 'upscale' sites you focus on or 'sites for upscale products'?

Comment: Thank you my fellow designers for your helpful comments. I really appreciate your time. To @bjb568, please right click on the image in its own browser, then click to enlarge it to view its original intended size. Does this help with legibility? When you say the button isn't full width, do you mean the text inside the button? I don't design logos.

Comment: The *page* isn't full-width

Comment: To @DA01: I reworded my introductory description. It makes a lot more sense now. Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: It's fine to update the question with your new version, but you can't expect people to continue re-critiquing it

Answer (score 2):

Just my opinion.....

> Does my website have a professional, high-end feel? Why are why not?

No. Using 3 separate typefaces - sans serif, serif, and script confuses the message. This is compounded when you change fonts mid-sentence like you've done with the script in the page content. "Creative designer of upscale and  high-end" is an incomplete sentence. Setting *only* that in the script makes little sense to me.

Consistency when choosing typefaces would offer more "high-end", "professional" appearances to me. Either use a serif or a sans serif. If you want to use a script, set an *entire* thought in the script. To me, the script you've chosen is also pretty low on the readability scale - even at the full image size.

> Does my current "Call To Action" button stand out or can you find it easily without much thought?

Sort of.... Due to the lack of content, yes the single button is easily found. However, if the page had more content a purple button in the middle of a purple page will be lost.

When you have a dark page frame you subconsciously tell users that anything dark is part of the page chrome. Users will inherently tend to look over or not pay attention to those areas which match the page chrome (banner blindness to a degree). By creating a purple button you've hidden the CTA a bit. As posted, it does somewhat work as it currently is, but with 4 or 5 more paragraphs of text, a couple more images, etc. it'll be lost or at least much less prominent.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the call to action blends into the rest of the design. Using a different color (green would work well) would make it stand out more. Another option is to give it more spacing.

The design is ok, but I would stick to 2 fonts - the cursive font is hard to read, so might recommend dropping that. Also the design is a bit cramped in areas. I would look at increasing the vertical spacing and making it more consistent.

Comment: Thank you. I just posted an updated image. I forgot to increase the amount of space between the purple header and the content beneath, but I will be sure to do that before this goes live. I agree, it is a little cramped. Thank you so much.